# How to integrate third-party keyboards in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, ime

I have developed a keyboard (C#) with different layouts and also suggest some words on entering on TextBox but it is still in the application level I would like to integrate it with TSF which makes my keyboard available through out Windows 8. I figured out that I need to register the Text service with TSF in (in-proc server).

How to integrate  keyboard in Windows 8?

[image]